# YouTubePlayer API lifecycle

Tags: android, youtube

Task:
Accomplishing auto play of YouTube video inside app, e.g. (pause in onPause, play in onResume)

I have a fragment class which contains this callback method for initializing the YouTubePlayer object.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    activePlayer = player;
    ...
}
```

In onResume calling play() or seekToMillis() does nothing.

What's the reason? Upon further inspection, YouTube's docs state:

"The YouTubePlayer supports state saving, which is managed automatically by the YouTubePlayer.Provider of the player. The saved state includes the loaded videos, the current playback position and player configurations such as the current YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle or fullscreen control flags. The state does not include any of the listeners that may be set on the player, so they need to be set again after the player is recreated."

How does one utilize SaveState to resume playback after the player is recreated?